# Detecting and avoiding overlapping words in a word cloud

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, word-cloud

I am trying to make word cloud using python image library. I am randomly placing words on canvas but I am getting words overlapped so how can I detect overlapping words and properly place them without overlappng. Please suggest me any algorithm in python.

Here is the word cloud:
[image]

Comment: you'll have to keep track of the bounding box of each word, and check for collisions before placing each new one.

Comment: Or use a [library](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/) someone else has written...

Comment: Wouldn't it be desirable to associate some meaning with the placement of the words, instead of placing them in random positions? This is something that always bugged me about these word clouds (that you have a 2D arrangement, but it's meaningless).